# MKMapView - NSUnknowKeyException

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, mkmapview

I want to use `MKMapView` with `UITabbarController`. I havent any problems with other viewController application. But if i use `MKMapView` with `UITabBarController`, `MKMapView` `IBOutlet` throws `NSUnknownKeyException` with message "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key xxxx"

If i delete `IBOutlet` from my code and IB then application runs fine. If i set a `IBOutlet` for `MKMapView` application throws this exception.

Answer (score 1):

On the TabBarController change the UIViewController that will display your map to match:

```
@interface MyMapViewController {
 MKMapView *mapView;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
```

On your tab bar controller use the inspector to change the class from UIViewController to MyMapViewController

Comment: It returns: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mapView.'